# alignas и структура

Tags: c++

Читаю книжку и не понял такой момент.
У нас есть структура

```
MyStruct ms{42,"hello"};
```

И ,как я понимаю, здесь мы выравниваем ее по 16:

```
alignas(16) auto [u,v] = ms;
```

И ,как я думаю, u и v должны также быть выравнены по этой границе ,но в книжке написано:"Here, we align the initialized anonymous entity and not the structured bindings u and v. This means
that u as the first member is forced to be aligned to 16 while v is not."
Хотя на других сайтах увидел, что выравниваются все члены. Я что-то не так понимаю,почему так ? Cпасибо

Comment: вы же выравниваете поле, а не структуру

Comment: @ARHovsepyan а почему u выравнивается ,но не v?

Comment: вы же сами говорите, выравнивать  объект(std::tuple)[u,v]  до 16 байт, а  он содержит два элемента, а эта инструкция выполняется для одного.

Comment: По идее тут ни `u`, ни `v` не будут выравнены. Структура вообще не трогается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structured binding структуры не создает N отдельных переменных. Он создает одну, безымянную.

`u` и `v` - не отдельные переменные, а сокращенные обозначения полей этой безымянной переменной типа `MyStruct`.

Поскольку переменная одна, одна выравнивается только вся целиком. Никакие дополнительные отступы между полями из-за `alignas` не вставляются.

Comment: спасибо за помощь !